# How to reference a theorem displayed between pauses in beamer?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I'm writing a presentation using `beamer` which at some point, in a proof, uses `only<X>` to display some parts of the proof. Inside these macros I show some theorem which I'd like to reference afterwards, however I always get the `<refname> has been referenced but does notexist, replaced by a fixed one` error and the `??` instead of the number.

A MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{One}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:one}\end{thm}

\only<2>{
    \begin{thm}    % I want to reference this one!
    \label{thm:one_hidden}
    \end{thm}
}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Two}
See theorem~\ref{thm:one} and~\ref{thm:one_hidden}
% output:
% See theorem 0.1 and ??
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can this be done in any way? Or do I have to place the theorem outside the `only<X>` macro?

---

Note: `\uncover` does **not** do what I want. It simply hides the text but it still takes space:

[image: Output of the MWE with <code>\uncover</code>]

while I want:

[image: Output of the MWE with <code>\only</code>]

With the final `??` replaced with `0.2` as in the output using `\uncover`.

The outputs were produced from this modified version of the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{One}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:one}A\end{thm}

\only<2>{   % or \uncover<2>{
    \begin{thm}
    \label{thm:one_hidden}
    B
    \end{thm}
}

\begin{thm}
C
\end{thm}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Two}
See theorem~\ref{thm:one} and~\ref{thm:one_hidden}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just observation: the theorems are not numbered.

Comment: Use `\uncover` instead of `\only`.

Comment: @Sigur In the actual presentation they are indeed numbered, but that wasn't necessary to provide a *minimal* example for  the problem I care about.

Comment: @Sigur `\uncover` does **not** do what I want. I want the behaviour of `\only`, i.e. when the text is not shown it should *not* occupy space. `\uncover` simply hides the text but it still takes space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to specify the overlay number for the label

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{One}
        \begin{thm}\label<1>{thm:one}\end{thm}

        \only<2>{
            \begin{thm}    % I want to reference this one!
                \label<2>{thm:onehidden}
            \end{thm}
        }

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Two}
        See theorem~\ref{thm:one} and~\ref{thm:onehidden}
        % output:
        % See theorem 0.1 and ??
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea that `\label` could use that syntax!